# Estimating the mean of a random variable with infinite variance from data

Tags: probability

After writing the text, I notice that it is probably unnecessary large. I always struggle to formulate in a compact way. I hope it is still understandable and not too much trouble to read. 
I have sereval questions here, the first one will seemingly have nothing to do with the title, but I will come to that. To give a context, my question arose when I had to calculate several quantities from Monte Carlo simulations I currently run. The random vectors that are produced there do not have finite variance, but finite mean. Without going into detail, this property is expected from the model.

1. A basic question, but I suddenly am unsure whether my approach was correct. I want to estimate the characteristic function of a random variable $X$ from data. As an estimator, I would use
   $$ \mathbb{E}\left(e^{i t X}\right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i e^{i t X_i} $$
   with values from the data. Is this correct? If so, I wondered how to estimate the statistical error. I just did the same as in other Monte Carlo simulation: I can estimate the standard deviation of $\cos(t X)$ and $\sin(t X)$ from my sample and have the error as the standard deviation divided by $\sqrt{N}$. Is that plausible? Because the characteristic function will be important in the next question.
2. Now to problem at hand. Let $X$ be a random vector (6-dimensional, in fact) and $W(X)$ its probability density function. I do not have closed expression of $W$, hence why I simulate and compare to some analytical results I found. To be precise, let $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R} $ be some function, then $f(X)$ is a random variable and for some functions, I have a closed expression for the expectation $\mathbb{E}f(X)$. In the simplest case, I know what the mean of $||X||$ is and I want to compare my result with the simulation data.
   As far as I know, as opposed to some miconceptions, the law of large numbers does hold for random variables with infinite variance, but the proof is harder and the convergence slower, which is what I observe in the data.
   It should be noted that some projections $u^T X$ have a stable distribution with index of stability $\alpha = 3/2$, but $X$ is not multivariate stable distributed. I note that, because for such a stable distribution, one can easily show that the sample average of size $N$ is also stable distributed with a scale parameter $c \propto N^{-1/4}$, the "width" of the distribution declines much slower than in the usual case. 
    Though the complete multidimensional distribution is not stable distributed, it leads me to believe that the sample average over any random quantity does decline very slowly. 
   In the data, I observe just that. I have a sample size of $N = 10^5$, but the average of $||X||$ fluctuates a lot (meaning that, if repeat the whole simulation several times, I get vastly different values for the average from the sample), which makes it impossible to get the a result with any meaningful accurary. 
   In the end, I had one idea to solve the problem: The characteristic function. As is well established, the mean follows from the first derivative of the characteristi function. If $$\phi_{f(X)}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i t f(X)})$$ is the characteristic function of $f(X)$, the mean is $\overline{f(X)} = i \phi_{f(X)}'(0)$. So, what I did was pretty simple: Estimate the characteristic function from the data by estimating the mean $e^{i t f(X)}$ and do that specifically for very small value values of $t$, which allows me to numerically evaluate the the derivative at zero. And indeed, the value I get is in good agreement with my analytical solutions of the problem, which led me to believe that this would work. 
   However, I still find it a bit strange that it would work like that. For random variables with infinite variance, it is expected that the convergence to the mean is much slower, which I indeed observe in the data, but using an estimator of the characteristic function seemingly circumvents the problem, which just doesn't seem right. That is why I asked the first question: Making sure that I dint't overlooked something in the estimation of the characteristic function. 
   The question is: Is it possible and to use the estimator of the characteristic function to find the mean of some quantities and if yes, is it plausible that this approach would result in a much higher accurary for random variables with infinite variance?

EDIT: Well, that is a bit embarassing, but it seems did a mistake somewhere in the implementation of my program. An error in the calculation of average, even though that should be simple...because after changing, the fluctuation of the estimated mean is about the same in both approaches. So I am not sure if there is still something to answer here. Basically, my assumptions that the characteristic function gives a more accurate result for the mean might just be plain wrong.

Comment: You can get proper norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.